# Get all TsLint rules in tslint.json file

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, tslint

I'm configuring the [SonarTsPlugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) and I'm trying to figure out what to put in my tslint.json (I don't have one yet). To begin, I would like to enable all TypeScript rules available in SonarQube. I've found this one and randomly added it to my project:

```
{
    "jsRules": {
        "class-name": true,
        "comment-format": [
            true,
            "check-space"
        ],
        "indent": [
            true,
            "spaces"
        ],
        "no-duplicate-variable": true,
        "no-eval": true,
        "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
        "no-unsafe-finally": true,
        "one-line": [
            true,
            "check-open-brace",
            "check-whitespace"
        ],
        "quotemark": [
            true,
            "double"
        ],
        "semicolon": [
            true,
            "always"
        ],
        "triple-equals": [
            true,
            "allow-null-check"
        ],
        "variable-name": [
            true,
            "ban-keywords"
        ],
        "whitespace": [
            true,
            "check-branch",
            "check-decl",
            "check-operator",
            "check-separator",
            "check-type"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "class-name": true,
        "comment-format": [
          true,
          "check-space"
        ],
        "curly": true,
        "indent": [
            true,
            "spaces"
        ],
        "no-eval": true,
        "no-internal-module": true,
        "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
        "no-unsafe-finally": true,
        "no-var-keyword": true,
        "one-line": [
            true,
            "check-open-brace",
            "check-whitespace"
        ],
        "quotemark": [
            true,
            "double"
        ],
        "semicolon": [
            true,
            "always"
        ],
        "triple-equals": [
            true,
            "allow-null-check"
        ],
        "typedef-whitespace": [
            true,
            {
                "call-signature": "nospace",
                "index-signature": "nospace",
                "parameter": "nospace",
                "property-declaration": "nospace",
                "variable-declaration": "nospace"
            }
        ],
        "variable-name": [
            true,
            "ban-keywords"
        ],
        "whitespace": [
            true,
            "check-branch",
            "check-decl",
            "check-operator",
            "check-separator",
            "check-type"
        ]
    }
}
```

The TypeScript plugin works well with it, but I'm not sure it enables all possible rules. Does anyone have a tslint.json example which does it? Thank you.

Note: I launched the `tsc --init` command to generate a default config file, but I ask myself the same question. In SonarQube I see there are 100+ rules but the file only contains ~50.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full list of rules supported by TSLint [in their official documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/)

Comment: Alright, this is handy. So it's not possible, for example, to generate a tslint.json file from SonarQube config? This is too bad, and I feel it's a bit messy to have both a TypeScript quality profile in SonarQube and a custom config in the project. I wonder why it was implemented this way.